# WPF Tree View - Clicking any where on the root node should expand the child node

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using hierarchical data to populate tree view. Clicking the triangle icon of the root node would expand/collapse child nodes. 
I want this behavior: When I click anywhere on the root node, it should expand/collapse the child nodes. It should toggle between expand/collapse.

How can i achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried any coding?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<TreeView TreeViewItem.Selected="TreeViewItem_Selected"/>
```

and in the xaml.cs

```
private void TreeViewItem_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   TreeViewItem tvi = (TreeViewItem)e.OriginalSource;
   if (tvi != null)
      tvi.IsExpanded = !tvi.IsExpanded;
}
```

Reference : [WPF expand TreeView on single mouse click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195135/wpf-expand-treeview-on-single-mouse-click) and [How to expand WPF TreeView on single click of item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921972/how-to-expand-wpf-treeview-on-single-click-of-item)

Comment: It doesn't toggle between expand/collapse if i select the same node.

Comment: if i select the same node means..? check this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c1b15925-75ec-4142-bd0a-b8ca75cfd901/treeview-single-click-expansion-disable-double-click?forum=wpf